# I ask calloc to allocate memory for 10 chars, but it sizeof returns 8

Tags: c, pointers

I'm asking calloc to assign the sizeof of 11 chars:

```
someString = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
```

I'm then using printf to print out the size of someString obtained with sizeof.

```
printf("the size of callocked array is %lu\n", sizeof(someString));
```

However, what is reported isn't 11 bytes (since each char is a byte), but 8.

```
the size of callocked array is 8
```

And it's still eight even if calloc is asked to assign memory for 23 chars instead of 11.
What is going on?

Comment: `sizeof(somestring)` is the size of the pointer, not the string.

Comment: You cannot retrieve the size of allocated memory.

Comment: thanks. I'm guessing that's still in bytes? Does it vary with the type that the pointer points to? And how should I best go about getting the size of an array?

Comment: @Gerhardh there's no way at all?

Comment: You have to 'remember' what size you allocated.

Comment: nope. No way at all.

Comment: ... unless you implement your own memory allocator that provide extra functionality to query size of blocks. But not with standard `malloc`& friends

Comment: thanks. I guess I should close my questions then since I got my answer. Or one of you should put the comment in an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: There are already a few duplicates around.... Basicall no need to get another one.

Comment: @Daniel: Your question has already been closed as a duplicate 3 minutes ago. Therefore, it is not possible for anyone to post any answers to your question anymore. Only comments are possible now.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel oh. Didn't really look at the notifications or scrolled up/down the page, since the comments kept appearing as I posted my own comments, so didn't notice that. Thank you, in any case.